# Multiplying the generates of a ring by scalars produces an isomorphic ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider a collection of algebraically independent variables $X_1,\ldots X_n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $y_1,y_2,...$ be rational functions in $\mathbb{Q}(X_1,\ldots X_n)$ and consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[y_1,y_2,...]$ generated by these $y_1,y_2,...$.

Now consider $y_i':= n_iy_i$ where $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

Is $\mathbb{Z}[y_1',y_2',...]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[y_1,y_2,...]$?

(If $\mathbb{Z}$ was replaced with $\mathbb{Q}$ it would be obviously true. But with $\mathbb{Z}$ it seems less obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

If the $y_i$-s are algebraically independent over $\Bbb Z$ (which is the same as being algebraically independent over $\Bbb Q$), yes. Otherwise, it might not be the case. Trivially, consider the rational function $y=y_1=\frac12\in\Bbb Q(X_1,\cdots,X_m)$ and $n=n_1=2$. $\Bbb Z[y]=\Bbb Z[1/2]$, while $\Bbb Z[ny]=\Bbb Z[1]=\Bbb Z$. And $\Bbb Z[1/2]$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Thank you for the simple example. Are there any weaker conditions than the $y_i$'s being algebraically independent? I.e perhaps being Laurent polynomials in the $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$)?